# Change bootstrap .col width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the width of my column but it won't work just by putting width code.

Look at this picture to understand better :) (has to be aligned with the column below)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCkFS.jpg

HTML and CSS:

```
<div id="logo" class="col-10 col-lg-3" style="background-color:#FF7633; height: 100%; height: auto; float: left; position: relative; left: -1.4%">
    <h3 style="border-bottom: 2px black solid; height:auto; padding: 7px 30px; text-align: center;">ComputerBasen</h3>
    <h5 style="text-align:center;">Salg af brugte <br>computere & computerdele</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: why you want to change this ?

Comment: What you want exactly?

Comment: Look picture i uploaded

Comment: has to be aligned with the column below

Comment: Have you try Add with row?

Comment: No how do i do that?

Comment: can you give fiddle ?

Comment: What is fiddle?

Comment: @Mikic - As it is, your question is too broad. Try reading about bootstrap's basics... Read some tutorial, be sure to understand `container` and `row`...

Comment: Go to https://jsfiddle.net and write your code there, where we can see and play with. It will help us to see the problem, and show you exactly where the code is broken, and suggest ways to fix it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=BVbElqnSVM

Comment: dont worry about the other stuff i just want to change the width of the logo at the left upper cornor

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the width of your column in your pasted code. Only height.

You could overwrite the width (`... width:750px; ...`) but that will break all your responsiveness. You shouldn't change col-* width unless you're re-compiling bootstrap with less/sass.

Comment: How would i align with the column i have under it then? any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe there's a margin/padding screwing your col? Also cols must be nested in a row div. `<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"></div></div>`

Comment: It wont even let me do width:750px;